# TypeError: Date is not a constructor in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I am running a node js app and facing this strange issue.I am not facing this error in another node app.

When i tried to use the javascript date function i am getting error 
"TypeError: Date is not a constructor "

I tried the following

```
var now = new Date();
var date2 = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var dateformated = new Date("2018-05-31T11:37:03Z");
```

Should i need to import some package for this? What might be the issue. I have searched the stackoverflow pages but could not find one specific to node

Comment: You probably have overriden `Date`, do `console.log(Date)` what does it output?

Comment: @deepan, your code is all valid. You don't need any package. You or some script you are using has messed up the date. For example by doing `Date = 7` or similar nonsense. Check your scripts and reload.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on my fresher time while  define like `var Date = "1/1/2013";`

> You can't define a variable called "Date" because there's a built-in object in JS called that. So if you are used  anywhere in this kind of sense. The you should change the name to something else.